# Facing Issue while installing dependency issue in React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, eslint, prettier

I'm getting the following error when I attempt to install a new dependency in my React project:

```
C:\Users\abhinavverma Desktop Sodexo-Fe Matchiq-fe> npm i @cypress/instrument-cra 
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE 
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree, 
npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: match-iq@0.1.0 
npm ERR! Found: prettier@1. 19.1 
npm ERR! node_modules/prettier 
npm ERR! dev prettier@"^1.19.1" from the root project 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: 
npm ERR! peer prettier@">=2.0.0" from pretty-quick@3.1.1 I
npm ERR! node_modules/pretty-quick 
npm ERR! dev pretty-quick@"^3.0.0" from the root project 
npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry 
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps 
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\abhinavverma AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
npm ERR! C:\Users\abhinavverma\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs 2021-08-12T18_35_58_522Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Facing Issue while installing dependency issue in React project

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't just post screenshots of code or error text, as it makes it less likely people can/will help you and makes it hard for other people with similar problems to find your question. I've converted your image to text in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

run the command again with `--force` on the end.  It can't find the correct version of the dependency.  It looks like the version is wrong.